# How do I find repeated text in a RichTextBox ?

Tags: c#

How do I find repeated text in a RichTextBox? I need to change the colour too.

Comment: How do you define repeated text? Is there repeated text in this comment, for instance?

Comment: The question is not clear enough to be answered well.

Answer (score 4):

To find repeated *words* you could split the text by spaces, order it alphabetically and look for repeated instances by performing a sinle loop through the array of words.

Repeated phrases are more difficult to detect as you would need to try combinations of words, which is where things get highly recursive.

Comment: Make sure to use a regular expression to strip multiple whitespace.

Comment: I suggest storing these words along with there index in text for faster access

Answer (score 1):

To match repeated words in a string:
(From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main ()
    {

        // Define a regular expression for repeated words.
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(?<word>\w+)\s+(\k<word>)\b",
          RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Define a test string.        
        string text = "The the quick brown fox  fox jumped over the lazy dog dog.";

        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

        // Report the number of matches found.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found in:\n   {1}", 
                          matches.Count, 
                          text);

        // Report on each match.
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' repeated at positions {1} and {2}",  
                              groups["word"].Value, 
                              groups[0].Index, 
                              groups[1].Index);
        }
    }    
}
```

To change the colour of a segment of text in a RichTextBox:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.SelectionStart = 4;
rtb.SelectionLength = 7;
rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: only matches on adjacent words. will not find same word throughout the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string value = "She sells sea shells by the sea shore";
Regex.Split(value, @"\W+").ToList()
    .GroupBy(w => w)
    .Where(w => w.Count() > 1)
    .Select(w => w.Key).ToList()
    .ForEach(w => Console.WriteLine("'{0}' repeats in the string", w));
```