# richtextbox.find and select duplicate text

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I currently have a rich text box that I use to display a long string. I use the following code to select a list of 'important' items within the string to be in bold font.

```
foreach (string item in selectionList)
{
     if (item.Length != 0)
     {
          int charStart = richTextBox.Find(item);
          richTextBox.SelectionFont = selectedFont;
          richTextBox.Select(charStart, item.Length);
     }
 }
```

I'd like to know the most efficient way to select a duplicate item if it appears in the text. eg. (text to highlight in caps for this example) "I would like to order some BURGERS, CHIPS and CHIPS"

This is just example data, there are some duplicates in the data I am using so I do need to be able to handle this situation.
(This is the same query as this: [duplicate selection in text() XPath selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023566/duplicate-selection-in-text-xpath-selector) but in C#)

Currently, the item appears twice in the selectionList but my code only finds the first instance of the word in the richTextBox and the last instance is not highlighted. I'm working in VS2013 using C# and .net 4.0.

Thanks a lot,
Anya

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find repeated text in a RichTextBox ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244428/how-do-i-find-repeated-text-in-a-richtextbox)

Comment: Yep, that looks great! Except that I do need to select phrases rather than individual words.
And also, looking closer, that question is asking how to FIND duplicates, I am using a List<string> to hold my items and can find duplicates easily, I now need to know the most efficient way to SELECT all instances in the text rather than just the first.

Comment: And actually, it would be great to be able to select each duplicate inside the text box without needing duplicates in the selection list.
Eg. SelectionList = (burgers, chips) it would be great to be able to select every instance of each word automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with this, but I'm really looking for efficiency here. Can anyone make it better?

```
if (item.Length != 0)
{
     if (!richTextBox.SelectedText.Contains(item))
     {
         int charStart = richTextBox.Find(item);
         richTextBox.SelectionFont = selectedFont;
         richTextBox.Select(charStart, item.Length);
     }
     else
     {
         int charStart = richTextBox.Find(item);
         charStart = richTextBox.Find(item, charStart + item.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
          richTextBox.SelectionFont = selectedFont;
          richTextBox.Select(charStart, item.Length);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call Find() in a loop until -1 is returned.  Note that the call within the loop starts at the last found location + 1:

```
        foreach (string item in selectionList)
        {
            if (item.Length != 0)
            {
                int charStart = richTextBox.Find(item, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                while (charStart != -1)
                { 
                    richTextBox.SelectionFont = selectedFont;
                    richTextBox.Select(charStart, item.Length);
                    charStart = richTextBox.Find(item, charStart + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Looks like the right kind of thing, however this particular code results in an infinite loop if it can only find one instance!

Comment: ?...no, it works fine with only one instance.  I tested it.  The second call to Find() will return -1 when no more instances are found.  Show me your implementation...